# When will I have a binary car?

Tags: code-golf, sequence, binary

I noticed that my car's odometer was at 101101 when I got to work today. Which is a cool number because it's binary (and a palindrome, but that's not important). Now, I want to know when the next time I'll have a binary odometer reading. I can't read the odometer while I'm driving, because that would be dangerous, so it'll have to be binary either when I get to work or get home.

There's really bad traffic on the way to and from my office, so I have to take a different route each day.

For the purposes of this challenge, a day is a round trip and starts with my commute to work.

You'll need to take the initial reading of the odometer and a 10 element sequence representing the amount of miles each way. This sequence should be repeated until you get to a binary odometer reading. You should then output the number of days it takes until we get to a binary reading.

Both the milage for the route and the odometer reading will be positive integers. The count of days will either be `x` or `x.5`, so your output of the day count needs to support floating point for half days. If the day count is an integer, you don't need to output the `.0`. The odometer will always eventually reach a binary state.

Any form of input/output is acceptable and [standard loopholes](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default?lq=1) are disallowed.

Test cases:

```
101101, [27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27] == 165.0
1, [13, 25, 3, 4, 10, 8, 92, 3, 3, 100] == 22.5
2, [2, 3, 1, 2, 7, 6, 10, 92, 3, 7] == 2.0
```

Comment: Will a day result only ever be an integer or an integer plus a half?

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman Yes. Each step is half a day.

Comment: What should happen if the odometer never becomes binary?

Comment: @CatsAreFluffy It always will. You don't have to worry about that case.

Comment: *The days will be floating point.* Could you elaborate a bit on that?

Comment: @Dennis The day count will either be `x` or `x.5`. That's all I meant. If you want to display that by formatting a string, or some other method, that's fine. It just needs to be in the format `x` or `x.5`.

Comment: @MorganThrapp isn't that *fixed*-point?

Comment: @cat You might be right, my math terminology is shaky at best.

Comment: Where do you work/live that 3, 25 and 92 miles (km?) are regular acceptable commute distances?

Comment: @kingofzeal A wormhole.

Comment: Heh, I hit that mark just a few days earlier – [101101 km](http://22x.eu/s58)

Comment: How many digits in the odometer?  Actually, that doesn't matter, because it's a 1 that's lost in the roll-over.  So we can code as if it always has enough room for one more digit.  :-)

Comment: @TobySpeight It's a magical odometer with an infinite number of digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Jelly, <s>22</s> <s>17</s> 16 bytes

```
RịS+³DṀ=1
Ṡç1#SH
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=UuG7i1MrwrNE4bmAPTEK4bmgw6cxI1NI&input=&args=MQ+WzEzLCAyNSwgMywgNCwgMTAsIDgsIDkyLCAzLCAzLCAxMDBd)

#### How it works

```
Ṡç1#SH     Main link. Left input: n (initial reading). Right input: A (distances)

Ṡ          Compute the sign of n. Since n is positive, this returns 1.
 ç         Apply the helper link to 1, 2, 3, ... until...
  1#         one match is found. Return the match in an array.
    S      Compute the sum of the array. This yields the match.
     H     Halve the result.


RịS+³DṀ=1  Helper link. Left argument: k (integer). Right argument: A (distances)

R          Range; yield [1, ..., k].
 ị         Retrieve the elements of A at those indices.
           Indexing in modular in Jelly.
  S        Compute the sum of the retrieved distances.
   +³      Add n (left input) to the sum.
     D     Convert the sum to base 10.
      Ṁ    Get the maximum digit.
       =1  Compare it with 1.
```

Answer (score 6):

## Javascript, <s>68</s> <s>63</s> <s>61</s> <s>60</s> 52 bytes

5 bytes off thanks [@ETHproductions](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/42545/ethproductions). <s>2</s> <s>3</s> 11!! bytes off thanks [@NotthatCharles](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/13950/not-that-charles).

```
f=(i,a,m=0)=>/[^01]/.test(i+=a[m++%10])?f(i,a,m):m/2
```

[Test here.](http://vihan.org/p/esfiddle/?code=f%3D(i%2Ca%2Cm%3D0)%3D%3E%2F%5B%5E01%5D%2F.test(i%2B%3Da%5Bm%2B%2B%2510%5D)%3Ff(i%2Ca%2Cm)%3Am%2F2%0A%0A%0AF%3D(i%2Ca)%3D%3Ealert(f(i%2Ca))%0A%0AF(101101%2C%5B27%2C27%2C27%2C27%2C27%2C27%2C27%2C27%2C27%2C27%5D)%0AF(1%2C%5B13%2C25%2C3%2C4%2C10%2C8%2C92%2C3%2C3%2C100%5D)%0AF(2%2C%5B2%2C3%2C1%2C2%2C7%2C6%2C10%2C92%2C3%2C7%5D))

Comment: Darn, you beat me to it.

Comment: Would `(i+=a[++m%10])` work?

Comment: @ETHproductions. Good one!! I forgot it will always be 10

Comment: why not initialize r as 0.5?  Or not initialize `r` or `m` whatsoever (they should default to null, ie., 0)

Comment: @NotthatCharles. Starting with `.5` was smart, thanks... Unfortunately, javascript throws undefined instead setting `null` or `0` for uninitialized variables

Comment: You can also save a byte by making `m=0` in the initializer and increment after modulo (`m++%10`)... at which point you can just drop `r` entirely.  The whole method is then in the low 50s

Comment: @NotthatCharles. I was sure I tried that before, thanks again ;)

Answer (score 5):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), <s>29</s> <s>26</s> 25 bytes

```
`tvyyYs+V50<!A~]xx1Mf1)2/
```

Input format is

```
[27; 27; 27; 27; 27; 27; 27; 27; 27; 27]
101101
```

*EDIT (June 10, 2016): The following link replaces `v` by `&v` (**26 bytes**) to adapt to changes in the language*

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=YHQmdnl5WXMrVjUwPCFBfl14eDFNZjEpMi8&input=WzI3OyAyNzsgMjc7IDI3OyAyNzsgMjc7IDI3OyAyNzsgMjc7IDI3XQoxMDExMDEK)

```
`              ]           % do---while loop. Exit loop when top of stack is falsy
 t                         % duplicate. Takes first input (array) first time
  v                        % concat vertically (doubles length of array)
   yy                      % copy top two. Takes second input (todasy's value) first time
     Ys                    % cumulative sum of (repeated) miles each way
       +                   % add to today's value
        V                  % convert each number to a string
         50<!A             % true for strings than only contain '01 ' (ASCII less than 50)
              ~            % negate. This is the loop condition
                xx         % delete stack contents
                  1M       % push again array that tells which strings only contain '01 '
                    f1)    % pick index of first true entry
                       2/  % divide by 2
```

Answer (score 3):

### Lua, 108 Bytes

First time using the repeat..until loop in a codegolf!

```lua
function f(o,t)i=0repeat i,o=i+1,(o+t[i%#t+1]).."."o=o:sub(1,o:find("%.")-1)until tonumber(o,2)print(i/2)end
```

#### Ungolfed

```lua
function f(o,t)               -- o can either be a number or a string, t is a table
                              -- call it like f(2,{27,14,5...})
  i=0                         -- initialise the travel count
  repeat                      -- proceed like a do..while in C
    i,o=i+1,(o+t[i%#t+1]).."."-- increment i, and add t[i] to the odometer
    o=o:sub(1,o:find("%.")-1) -- remove the decimal part of the odometer
  until tonumber(o,2)         -- tries to convert o from binary to decimal
                              -- return nil (and repeat the loop) if it can't
  print(i/2)                  -- print i/2 which is the number of days for i travels
end
```

After the first loop, `o` will have a decimal part because of `tonumber`, I had to remove it... And to add it for the first case, that's why I concatenate it with a `"."`.

Answer (score 3):

### PowerShell, <s>84</s> <s>73</s> <s>67</s> <s>59</s> 57 bytes

```
param($a,$b)do{$a+=$b[$i++%10]}until(!+($a-replace1))$i/2
```

Takes input `$a` and `$b`, expecting `$b` to be an explicit array of mileages (e.g., `.\binary-car.ps1 1 @(13,25,3,4,10,8,92,3,3,100)`). We then enter a `do`/`until` loop. Each iteration, we increment `$a` with the mileage in `$b` at position `$i++ % 10` so that we continually loop through the array. This will start at zero since for the first loop the `$i` is not initialized, and so evaluates to `$null`, which equates to `0` in this context, and it's only *after* that evaluation that the `++` occurs.

Then, the `until` statement checks if our number is only `0` and `1` by first `-replace`ing all `1` with nothing, casting that back as an integer with `+`, and then taking the Boolean-not with `!`. If it evaluates true, we'll finish the loop, output `$i / 2`, and terminate the program.

**Explanation for the loop conditional --** In PowerShell, any non-zero integer is `$true`, and any non-empty string is also `$true`. For example, `231145` (an integer) will change to `"2345"` (a string) after the `-replace`, which will integer-cast as `2345` (an integer), the `!` of which is `$false`. However, `101101` (an integer) will change to `"00"` (a string) which will cast as `0` (an integer), the `!` of which is `$true`. If we didn't have the `+`, the `"00"` will `!` to `$false` since it's a non-empty string.

<sub>Edit - Saved 11 bytes by swapping equality-on-length for strictly-zero</sub>
<sub>Edit 2 -- Saved another 6 bytes by realizing that `$b.count` will always be `10` ...</sub>
<sub>Edit 3 -- Saved another 8 bytes by using do/until instead of for</sub>
<sub>Edit 4 -- If the object being `-replace`d is an integer value, don't need quotes, saving another 2 bytes</sub>

Answer (score 3):

## Java, 112 <s>miles</s> bytes

```
float c(int r,int[]d){float y=0;for(int i=0;;i%=d.length){y+=.5;r+=d[i++];if((""+r).matches("[01]+"))return y;}}
```

Answer (score 3):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 31 bytes

Code:

```
0IE\[²vs>sy+D§'aT«-""Qi\2/?}Ž}Ž
```

<s>Somehow, the code doesn't stop running (and I can't figure out why)</s>. Apparently I forgot that there are three loops going on instead of 2. So it would still get into an infinite loop...

[Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=MElFXFvCsnZzPnN5K0TCpydhVMKrLSIiUWlcMi8_fcW9fcW9&input=MQpbMTMsIDI1LCAzLCA0LCAxMCwgOCwgOTIsIDMsIDMsIDEwMF0)

Answer (score 2):

## Ruby, 58

Nothing special.  Just a cycle...

```ruby
->s,a,i=0{a.cycle{|e|i+=0.5;break i if/[2-9]/!~'%d'%s+=e}}
```

Comment: How do you run it?

Comment: @bogl It's a lambda - the easiest way is to append the params in square brackets.  Or you can assign the lambda to a variable and, again, append params in square brackets.  E.g., `->s,a,i=0{a.cycle{|e|i+=0.5;break i if/[2-9]/!~'%d'%s+=e}}[1, [13, 25, 3, 4, 10, 8, 92, 3, 3, 100]]` or... `f=->s,a,i=0{a.cycle{|e|i+=0.5;break i if/[2-9]/!~'%d'%s+=e}}; f[1, [13, 25, 3, 4, 10, 8, 92, 3, 3, 100]]`

Answer (score 1):

## Pyth, <s>36</s> <s>32</s> 30 bytes

```
Jvz.V0=J+J@QbI<ssM{`J2KbB;chK2
```

[Try it here!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Jvz.V0%3DJ%2BJ%40QbI%3CssM%7B%60J2KbB%3BchK2&input=1%0A%5B13%2C+25%2C+3%2C+4%2C+10%2C+8%2C+92%2C+3%2C+3%2C+100%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=101101%0A%5B27%2C+27%2C+27%2C+27%2C+27%2C+27%2C+27%2C+27%2C+27%2C+27%5D%0A1%0A%5B13%2C+25%2C+3%2C+4%2C+10%2C+8%2C+92%2C+3%2C+3%2C+100%5D%0A2%0A%5B2%2C+3%2C+1%2C+2%2C+7%2C+6%2C+10%2C+92%2C+3%2C+7%5D&debug=0&input_size=2)

#### Explanation

```
Jvz.V0=J+J@QbI<ssM{`J2KbB;chK2  # Q = input sequence

Jvz                             # assign starting value to J
   .V0                          # Start an infinite loop iterating over b starting at 0
      =J                        # Set J to
        +J                      # the sum of J
          @Qb                   # and the value at Q[b % len(q)]
             I                  # if
              <      2          # lower than 2
                  {`J           # Remove duplicate digits from J 
               ssM              # Map the remaning digits back to integers and sum them
                      KbB       # if the above evals to true, save b to K and leave the loop
                         ;      # End loop body
                           hK   # Increment K because we missed one loop increment
                          c  2  # and divide it by 2 to get the days
```

Answer (score 1):

## Mathematica, 92 bytes

```
(y=1;x=#+#2[[1]];While[!StringMatchQ[ToString@x,{"0","1"}..],x+=#2[[y++~Mod~10+1]]];N@y/2)&
```

Yep.
Input is the odometer and a list of times. Output is the day count.

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, <s>102</s> 98

```
function f($i,$s){while(1)foreach($s as$v){$d+=.5;$i+=$v;if(preg_match('/^[01]+$/',$i))return$d;}}
```

Ungolfed Version

```
function f($i,$s) {
    $d = 0;
    while(true) {
        foreach($s as $v) {
            $d += 0.5;
            $i+=$v;
            if(preg_match('/^[0|1]+$/', $i)) {
                return $d;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

PHP Notices can be removed of extra cost of 4 characters `$d = 0;` in golfed version.

Example

```
$i = 101101;
$s = [27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27, 27];
f($i,$s);
```

Comment: Removing the curly braces around the `if`, removing the 0 from `0.5`, and removing the `|` between the 1 and 0 in your regex saves you 4 bytes. `function f($i,$s){while(1)foreach($s as$v){$d+=.5;$i+=$v;if(preg_match('/^[01]+$/',$i))return$d;}}`

Comment: @Samsquanch, good suggestion, brackets and 0 before .5 clearly I missed. Changed now.

Answer (score 0):

## C Sharp, 180.

Dear lord C# is long.

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;class a{double c(int a,int[]b){var d=0.5;a+=b[0];var i=1;while(!Regex.IsMatch(a.ToString(),"^[01]+$")){a+=b[i];i+=1;i=i%10;d+=0.5;}return d;}}
```